# How to use sort function and search function (regexp) together without strange errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, sorting

In this prototype, I have "products" that are each individually stored in a div along with their price. I have added four buttons that sort the divs containing the products in alphabetical order (A-Z AND Z-A) as well as by price (lowest to highest and highest to lowest). These sorting functions work perfectly by themselves. I also have a search bar that acts as a search engine if you like an upon entering each character into the input field, will eliminate the products (div's) by name if they do not contain that letter(s). I have done this using a regular expression. This also worked by itself until I adapted it to try and work in conjunction with the sorting mechanisms.

**Problem**

I would like to be able to search for "products" using the search functionality to display the correct results regardless of what order the products have been sorted into.

**Question**

How is it possible to be able to display only the div's that contain the letter(s) searched for in the search bar regardless of the ordering (e.g. Z to A).

I think I ruined the search function itself by adding the `index` variable but you can't do `list.name[i].match(res)` can you? There is something wrong with the logic behind the search function. I believe the function that needs serious fixing is the `searchProducts` function.

**The code AFTER I adapted the searchProducts function is below...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="resultsSpan"></div>
<div id="product0" style="height:60px; width:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div id="product1" style="height:60px; width:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div id="product2" style="height:60px; width:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div id="product3" style="height:60px; width:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<button onclick="sortprods()">
Sort A-Z
</button>
<button onclick="sortprods2()">
Sort Z-A
</button>
<button onclick="sortprods3()">
Price (low to high)
</button>
<button onclick="sortprods4()">
Price (high to low)
</button>
<input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="searchProducts()"/>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var list = [
    {name: "Apple", price: 31}, 
    {name: "Banana", price: 22},
    {name: "Orange", price: 46},
    {name: "Strawberry", price:76}
    ];

list.sort(AtoZ);
for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML = list[i].name + ", " + list[i].price;
    }

function AtoZ(a,b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

function ZtoA(a,b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return 1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

function LowtoHigh(a,b) {
  if (a.price < b.price)
    return -1;
  if (a.price > b.price)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

function HightoLow(a,b) {
  if (a.price < b.price)
    return 1;
  if (a.price > b.price)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

function sortprods(){
list.sort(AtoZ);
currentSort = "AtoZ";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML = list[i].name + ", " + list[i].price;
    }
}

function sortprods2(){
list.sort(ZtoA);
currentSort = "ZtoA";
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("product" + j).innerHTML = list[j].name + ", " + list[j].price;
    }
}

function sortprods3(){
currentSort = "LowtoHigh";
list.sort(LowtoHigh);
    for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
        document.getElementById("product" + k).innerHTML = list[k].name + ", " + list[k].price;
    }
}

function sortprods4(){
currentSort = "HightoLow";
list.sort(HightoLow);
    for (var l = 0; l < list.length; l++) {
        document.getElementById("product" + l).innerHTML = list[l].name + ", " + list[l].price;
    }
}

var input = "";
var index = [];
var currentSort = "AtoZ";
function searchProducts(){
    input = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
    if(input == ""){
        document.getElementById("product0").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("product1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("product2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("product3").style.display = "block";
    }else{
        switch(currentSort){
            case "AtoZ":
                list.sort(AtoZ);
                for(var a = 0; a < list.length; a++){
                    document.getElementById("product" + a).innerHTML = list[a].name + ", " + list[a].price;
                    index.push(list[a].name);
                }
                index.sort();
            break;
            case "ZtoA":
                list.sort(ZtoA);
                for(var b = 0; b < list.length; b++){
                    document.getElementById("product" + b).innerHTML = list[b].name + ", " + list[b].price;
                    index.push(list[b].name);
                }
                index.sort();
                index.reverse();
            break;
            case "LowtoHigh":
                list.sort(LowtoHigh);
                for(var c = 0; c < list.length; c++){
                    index.push(list[c].price);
                }
                index.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
            break;
            case "HightoLow":
                list.sort(HightoLow);
                for(var d = 0; d < list.length; d++){
                    index.push(list[d].price);
                }
                index.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
            break;
        }
        test = input;
        re = new RegExp(test, 'gi');
        for(var e=0; e<index.length; e++){
            if(index[e].match(re)){
                document.getElementById("product"+e).style.display = "block";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("product"+e).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

**The code before I adapted the `searchProducts` function (THAT WORKED PERFECTLY BEFORE ADAPTION) is...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="searchProducts()"/>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2">

    <div id="product1" style="background-color:red; height:100px; width:100px; float:left">chocolate<br /><button onClick="grow()" id="button1">Show Info</button></div>

    <div id="product2" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; width:100px; float:left">Mint</div>

    <div id="product3" style="background-color:green; height:100px; width:100px; float:left">Caramel</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var index = ["Chocolate", "Mint", "Caramel"];
var input = "";
var currentLog = [];
function searchProducts(){
    currentLog = [];
    input = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
    /*function searchStringInArray(str, strArray){
        for (var j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            if (strArray[j].match(str)){
                var temp = strArray.slice(j, (j + 1));                      
                currentLog.push(temp);
                console.log(j);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentLog.join("<br />");
        if(currentLog.length < 1){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No results were found.";
        }
    }*/
        test = input;
        re = new RegExp(test, 'gi');
/*if(!index[0].match(re)){
document.getElementById("product1").style.display = "none";
}
if(!index[1].match(re)){
document.getElementById("product2").style.display = "none";
}
if(!index[2].match(re)){
document.getElementById("product3").style.display = "none";
}*/
    for(var e=0; e<index.length; e++){
            if(!index[e].match(re)){
        document.getElementById("product"+(e+1)).style.display = "none";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("product"+(e+1)).style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("product1").style.display == "none" && document.getElementById("product2").style.display == "none" && document.getElementById("product3").style.display == "none"){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no results";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
        }
    /*searchStringInArray(input, index);*/
}

function grow(){
    if(document.getElementById('product1').style.height == "200px"){
        document.getElementById('product1').style.height = '100px';
        document.getElementById('button1').innerHTML = "Show Info";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('product1').style.height = "200px";
        document.getElementById('button1').innerHTML = "Hide Info";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I also get a different error in the console log every time I click on or enter a different letter, sometimes it says `index[e].match isn't a function` or `property style of null`

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian Please help me with this

Comment: I think you should reorganize your code: put function in the head tag, and run just the initialization for loop on `window.onload`. Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alexmario/7ay17L9e/).

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I appreciate you taking the time to try, but your JSFiddle doesn't work. Enter in the letter n for example. Look at the results and backspace, Enter the letter n in again in the search, and then look at the results, click backspace and repeat this process 5 times. Each time one less product is displayed until eventually it shows none, and this is just using the search function without any sorting mechanisms. Please try to fix your fiddle. Again thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Right, as far as I can see the problem with your search function is in the `index` varaible. You continue to add elements each time you call the function. But you're using the index array index (sorry but the variable should have a better name), to get the div of the fruit, but in the second run, you have a null error that stop the search. As you sort the index, the match part never catch the match out the first elements that depends on the sort...Hope this helps.

Comment: Have a look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ay17L9e/1/) now. If you use the 'index' please clear your purpose, so we can help. I think you should remove all the sorting part in your search function as it is not need. But if you did to achieve something, please update your question and explain it.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I do need both the sorting functions and the search function, they are both needed in the final product. I shall have a look at the JSFiddle now

Comment: It is ok, but my advise is just to reviewing those parts.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini If you sort the items using Z-A and then search for the letter 'N', nothing happens. It still doesn't work how I want it to.

Comment: I don't know if this makes sense but I want to be able to sort those products, and then be able to search for products regardless of what order they are sorted in.

Comment: @Ali could you please help with this question?

Comment: Or possibly @Ωmega ?????

Comment: Or possibly @p.s.w.g ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you sort your list when a filter was applied earlier, you only move the data, not the visibility of the containers of those data.

Instead you could re-execute the regex matching, every time you display the content according to the current sort order. That way you are sure the right data are visible at all times.

You have a lot of duplication in your code, with several places where you have the same loop, or code that only differs in one aspect. You should always try to "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY).

I would suggest to have one function for displaying content only. You could pass it the sort function to apply. Note that this means the HTML also changes where you have specified the event handlers. There are many other such simplifications, which are too many to mention all.

Check this snippet:

```js
var list = [
    {name: "Apple", price: 31}, 
    {name: "Banana", price: 22},
    {name: "Orange", price: 46},
    {name: "Strawberry", price:76}
];
var currentRegex = /./; // any character matches
var currentSort = AtoZ;
// Call the function we have for applying the initial sort order and filter
searchProducts(document.getElementById('searchbar').value);
// Shorter ways to compare:
function AtoZ(a,b) { return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ?  1 : 0; }
function ZtoA(a,b) { return AtoZ(b,a) }
function LowtoHigh(a,b) { return a.price - b.price }
function HightoLow(a,b) { return b.price - a.price }

// One function for all sort orders: pass sort order as function
function sortprods(sorter) {
    var showCount = 0;
    currentSort = sorter;
    list.sort(currentSort);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var product = document.getElementById("product" + i);
        // use textContent, not innerHTML
        product.textContent = list[i].name + ", " + list[i].price;
        var show = !!list[i].name.match(currentRegex);
        product.style.display = show ? "" : "none";
        showCount += show;
    }
    document.getElementById('resultsSpan').textContent = 
        showCount ? '' : 'no results';
}

function searchProducts(input){
    // Argument is value of input
    // No need to `switch` on currentSort. Can do this with generic code.
    // Deal with empty input by using all-matching `.` regexp. 
    // `g` not needed.
    currentRegex = new RegExp(input.length ? input : '.', 'i'); 
    sortprods(currentSort);
}
```

```html
<div id="resultsSpan"></div>
<div id="product0" style="height:45px; width:60px; background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<div id="product1" style="height:45px; width:60px; background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<div id="product2" style="height:45px; width:60px; background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<div id="product3" style="height:45px; width:60px; background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<button onclick="sortprods(AtoZ)">Sort A-Z</button>
<button onclick="sortprods(ZtoA)">Sort Z-A</button>
<button onclick="sortprods(LowtoHigh)">Price (low to high)</button>
<button onclick="sortprods(HightoLow)">Price (high to low)</button>
<input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="searchProducts(this.value)"/>
```

#### About the ternary operator:

You asked in comments about the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
product.style.display = list[i].name.match(currentRegex) ? "" : "none";
```

The above is equivalent to this:

```
var temp; 
if (list[i].name.match(currentRegex)) {
    temp = "";
} else {
    temp = "none";
}
product.style.display = temp;
```

... except that no `temp` variable is created of course.

The other occurrence:

```
currentRegex = new RegExp(input.length ? input : '.', 'i');
```

... is equivalent to:

```
var temp; 
if (input.length) { // if length is defined and not 0
    temp = input;
} else {
    temp = ".";
}
currentRegex = new RegExp(temp, 'i');
```

Comment: I knew the logic was wrong behind it but I didn't know how to move the visibility with the objects in the array but it appears you have done it successfully. Thank you so much for your assistance, I will check your answer out in the next minute or so and it will accept your answer if it works. As for repetitious code, I apologise but I was well aware of that just so you know, I laugh when I think about it but I code very sloppy when making prototypes and I had every intention to just makes one or two functions with parameters to clean the rest up. Thanks again, be back shortly @trincot

Comment: I just corrected an issue in the last line of the code. It should pass `currentSort` as argument: `sortprods(currentSort);`

Comment: The search function and sort functions do work correctly now, I only have one request before I accept your answer. There is one issue I noticed which was when you do a search under A-Z for example, the results aren't display in the assortment of A to Z.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your last comment where you fixed until now. Thank you for fixing that. I will accept your answer now. Thank you again for helping.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you in my comment @trincot

Comment: You're welcome. NB: Without tagging I still get notified of your comment, since it is posted under my answer ;-)

Comment: if you have the time would you mind explaining this? `(input.length ? input : '.', 'i');` I am just curious as to what each entity within those brackets is? Like I am not familiar with it. What do those parameters do? The first one is the pattern and the second is the modifier, I get that. So the translated into English, the pattern is the input (regardless of length), don't know what the question mark does or the `input:` and I am assuming the `'.'` is related to the modifier which means any case. The modifier is `i` which means case in-sensitive.

Comment: This line too if you don't mind. `= list[i].name.match(currentRegex) ? "" : "none";` I enjoy learning new things :). I get all of it up until the `(currentRegex) ? "" : "none";` bit.

Comment: `(input.length ? input : '.', 'i')` is a pair of arguments to `new RegExp`. The second argument is `'i'`, which I think is clear. The first argument uses the ternary operator: `input.length ? input : '.'`. It is like an `if ... then ... else` that you can use within expressions. So it means *"if input has a length (> 0) then use its value, otherwise use '.'"*. It avoids passing the empty string, and uses the point in that case, which matches everything.

Comment: Check out the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). So `list[i].name.match(currentRegex) ? "" : "none";` means *If `list[i].name` matches with the regexp then use "", otherwise "none"*. This value then gets assigned to the `display` style.

Comment: That makes sense now

Comment: Added a paragraph about it in my answer as well ;-)

Comment: thank you! @trincot I also may have another question for you later on in the week which I will tag you in, IF I need help. I am hoping I will be smart enough to solve it now :).

Comment: what would be the easiest way to test whether they were all set to displa:none; and then display a span saying something like "No results" ?

Comment: I just added code to display "no results" when needed.